# No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined error with javaconfig

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm having some problems adding spring security. It shows an error that says:No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined

```
public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {


        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(App.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));


       // security filter
        servletContext.addFilter(
                "springSecurityFilterChain",
                new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"))
                .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        webContext.register(WebConfig.class);
        webContext.setServletContext(servletContext);


        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(webContext));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }
}
```

In the moment I add the security filter, it shows this error. I've been like crazy trying to resolve this with no success.

This is my **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("tom").password("123456").roles("USER");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("bill").password("123456").roles("ADMIN");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("james").password("123456").roles("SUPERADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/signin").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .and().formLogin();

    }
}
```

**WebConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(value = {"com.hp.visitor.controller"})
@Import({ WebSecurityConfig.class })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver(){
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }

}
```

I've been trying a lot, but it always shows an 503 error.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Instead of manually instantiating the proxy in the middle of your code, move it into a bean method.

Comment: Is your `WebSecurityConfig.class` imported via `@Import` on `WebConfig`?

Comment: yes, I have this the import annotation and I'm getting this error

I have this in the webconfig class

@Import({ WebSecurityConfig.class }). I'm gonna add it in the question

Comment: I think the `WebSecurityConfig` needs to be loaded by the root context not the dispatcher context.

Comment: What's happening is that `DelegatingFilterProxy` looks for `springSecurityFilterChain` bean in root context while it's declared in web app context. Register the filter as Charlires comment. But you don't need to forcedly move @EnableWebSecurity configuration to root context. In many situations, it's more correct to have it in web context. You can make the filter to look for it in the web context with:
`securityFilter.setInitParameter("contextAttribute", "org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT." + "dispatcher")`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try registering the security filter this way

```
FilterRegistration.Dynamic securityFilter = servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", DelegatingFilterProxy.class);
    securityFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
```

And add the `@Import({WebSecurityConfig.class})` in the configuration class you declare as your rootContext in **WebInitializer** in your case is in **App.java**

Answer (score 12):

You can simply create a class that extends from AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer and it will automatically create/initialize the security filter chain for you.  No code needed:

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {}
```

Also, if you're only just creating a single dispatcher servlet, you could consider simply extending your WebAppIntializer class from AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer:

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebSecurityConfig.class, App.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{
            "/"
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You do not actually need to add the security filter manually. You can extend `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer`, which will insert the filter. You do not need to add any additional code than what is in the example below:

```
package com.example.spring.security.config;

import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

@Order(1)
public class SecurityWebAppInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

I typically will have my Security App Initializer with `@Order(1)` and the standard Web App Initializer with `@Order(2)`.

You also need to make sure that your component scan is setup correctly. I have had it pointing at a wrong package and I have gotten this error before.