# Spring Security with Spring MVC does not working

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'v just created a Spring MVC Project via Eclipse, and then i added this classes:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

and

```
public class SpringSecurityInitializer
      extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

just like [The Reference says](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/), but i am only getting an exception:

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:529)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1095)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:277)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1097)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:324)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235)
at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4615)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5222)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1683)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am losing my mind with this, because i am not getting able to add security to my application, can you please help me with this headache?

I added `@Order(1)` to my `SpringSecurityInitializer` and still not working with the same exception.
Maybe i forgot something, just let me know ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look @ [No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined error with javaconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23572516/no-bean-named-springsecurityfilterchain-is-defined-error-with-javaconfig)

It might help you.

add the `@Import({WebSecurityConfig.class})` in the configuration class you declare as your rootContext in `WebInitializer`

Answer (score -1):

You need to configure the Spring Security Filter in web.xml:

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: But that is equivalent to the class `SpringSecurityInitializer`, that is what the reference says. Take a look around [THIS GUIDE](http://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/#abstractsecurity-webapplicationinitializer)

Comment: @Vercryger Yes, you are right. However, your filter *order* may be off, add `@Order(1)` to your `SpringSecurityInitializer`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't note this class in you question. It should work that way

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Sorry bro, i added that and the same exception :(