# NullPointerException at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.getFilters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, filter, spring-security

I tried to use spring-security, and get this error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.getFilters(FilterChainProxy.java:223)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:196)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I include filter in web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And create a bean for this filter in applicationContext file:

```
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy"> </bean>
```

Before I register this bean in applicationContext file I Have an error `no bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined`

I don't use spring-security.xml for configuration, and configure security in a SecurityConfig class.

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void registerGlobalAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and();

    http.formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("j_username")
            .passwordParameter("j_password")
            .permitAll();

    http.logout()
            .permitAll()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true);

}
```

}

I think that is some problems with configuration of spring-security file, but I can't understand what is wrong.

Comment: the /* in the web.xml, after the <url-pattern>  is right?

Comment: @melli-182 yes, I think this is right

Comment: but making that comment , it causes the filter-mapping and url-pattern tag never close.

Comment: @melli-182 no, it's not a comment, it looks like a comment in a code section, in .xml this is (/*) not symbol for comments

Comment: Have you had a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23572516/no-bean-named-springsecurityfilterchain-is-defined-error-with-javaconfig ? Maybe it would be easier if you only used either xml or java configuration.

Comment: @Ales oh you are right!!! I get confused by the code represented in your post!!! Thanks!

Comment: You have not given your complete configuration. I have answered using a "working" configuration below. If you need to know specifically what is wrong please provide your complete web.xml

Comment: @ArunM I add a full web.xml file

Comment: Did you try the below approach ? It should work ..

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out what is going on here, but I think you are much better off sticking to only Java Config or XML config rather than mixing and matching them in relation to integration Spring MVC and Security.

In XML Configuration, The springSecurityFilterChain is created by the `http` namespace in your spring-security.xml. Refer [here](http://www.baeldung.com/no-bean-named-springsecurityfilterchain-is-defined). Since you have switched to java config there is no springSecurityFilterChain created which is exactly what the application is complaining about.

To Create the springSecurityFilterChain in you need to do the following 2 steps.

**Step 1**

Remove the following from your web.xml

```
 <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

**Step 2**

Create a `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` which will create the springsecurityfilterchain for you.

```
public class SpringSecurityInitializer extends
        AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

Now `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/context/AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.html) says that 
*When used with AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer(), this class is typically used in addition to a subclass of AbstractContextLoaderInitializer.*

So now you have to create AbstractContextLoaderInitializer yourself. For this I have made 2 changes

Step 1 :- Remove  below from web.xml

```
   <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

   <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
```

Step 2:- Create a Class `SpringAnnotationWebInitializer` and `ApplicationContextSpring` which will have the following content

```
public class SpringAnnotationWebInitializer extends
        AbstractContextLoaderInitializer {

    @Override
    protected WebApplicationContext createRootApplicationContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.register(ApplicationContextSpring.class);
        return applicationContext;
    }

}
```

and `ApplicationContextSpring` will be

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
@Import(SecurityConfig.class)
public class ApplicationContextSpring {

}
```

Like I said, you are much better of creating either java or xml config.

Comment: I tried thus solution, but have this error  again `No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined`

Comment: Completely changed my answer above. Please go through it now

Comment: thanks, I agree, better I will try to create .xml configuration

Comment: I'm sorry) I tried your first variant again,  add to web.xml only this `<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
  </filter-class>
 </filter>
 
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
 `
and it's working, you can edit your question to first variant and I mark it as true, thanks)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a `FilterChainProxy` bean with an `null` filter list in your XML configuration and this bean is than used in the web.xml by `DelegatingFilterProxy`. `FilterChainProxy#getFilters` tries to iterate over the `null` list and naturally fails with a `NullPointerException`.

The root of the problem is, that you cannot mix Java configuration and traditional XML configuration like this. The Java configuration creates a separate `FilterChainProxy` bean that has nothing to do with the bean configured via XML.