# NullPointerException. Spring security filter failed

Tags: java, spring, security, nullpointerexception, jwt

I have no ideas why this app does not start displaying this error. I tried to use Spring Security and JWT.

```
2020-Feb-17 12:29:07 PM [main] INFO  org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy - Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,javax.servlet.ServletResponse,javax.servlet.FilterChain) throws javax.servlet.ServletException,java.io.IOException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
2020-Feb-17 12:29:07 PM [main] INFO  org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy - Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(javax.servlet.FilterConfig) throws javax.servlet.ServletException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
2020-Feb-17 12:29:07 PM [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Exception starting filter [jwtRequestFilter]
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:241) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:270) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:106) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4533) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5172) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) [?:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
```

This is filter code. I don't understand what is wrong with it. The application just crushed upon loading time with null pointer exception related to the security filter.

```
@Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String email = null;
        String jwtToken = null;

        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("FC ")) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.replace("FC ", "");
            try {
                email = jwtTokenUtil.getEmailFromToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with FC String");
        }

        if (email != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(email);
            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

@UPDATE

added method where I add filter.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/service/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31402509/12576990

Comment: How do you add the filter?

Comment: NatFar, I add filter.

Comment: Maybe it's not related to your problem but I am wondering why are you trying to authenticate the user manually by parsing the JWT token? Since you are using Spring Security 5.2.2.RELEASE, all that job is already done for you. The only thing you have to do is to indicate the authorization server uri: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-minimalconfiguration and adapt roles if needed: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization-extraction

Comment: akuma8, I don't have authorization server so I verify token myself.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing exactly the same issue and it was the spring aop configuration that I had in my app. I added a pointcut to exclude GenricFilterBean class implementation and everything seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and I resolved it in this way:

1- create a custom annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface NoLogging
{
}
```

2- annotate the doFilterInternal

```
    @Override
    @NoLogging
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
```

3- exclude the methods annotated with this annotation from AOP:

```
@Before(value = "execution(* com.company..*..*(..)) && !@annotation(com.company.aop.NoLogging)")
    public void logEntry(JoinPoint joinPoint)
```

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the game here but i just had this same exception. The clue is the CGLIB proxies in the INFO above the null pointer and the Generic Filter exception. Do you have @Transactional anywhere in here? Have you defined any transactional functionality around these methods? I had @Transactional on my doFilterInternal. Removing the @Transactional fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this because didn't registered Filter with FilterRegistrationBean. After this error disappeared.
https://www.techiedelight.com/how-to-define-custom-filters-spring-boot-application/
second case

Answer (score 0):

I might be bit late here, but i also faced this issue and was able to debug the actual reason as to why it happens.
Spring AOP creates proxies by extension and we have a `init()` defined in GenericFilterBean

```
public final void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
...
}
```

Since the init method is defined as **final** and final methods and classes can't be extended which is the necessity for creating proxies. Hence SpringAOP is not able to create a proper proxy for this method and delegation of method call from proxy object to target object fails and it returns **null** value from proxy object.

In short,
All the classes or methods which are defined as final in java will have issues when you are using SpringAOP.

So, the solution like other users have mentioned is to exclude the **GenericFilterBean** using AOP pointcuts.