# Spring4 Security configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-4

I'm using Spring4 with tomcat, my web.xml follow:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/resources/beans.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<resource-ref>
    <description>MySQL Datasource</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/informagiovani</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

My beans.xml is the follows and is empty because all the beans I need are defined with annotation:

```
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />

</beans>
```

I defined the *spring-servlet.xml* as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="it.informagiovani" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

I defined the security configuration as I found on a Spring documentation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("giacomo").password("230483").roles("ADMIN");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

  http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll() 
    .antMatchers("/addUser").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    .antMatchers("/saveUser").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    .and().formLogin();


}
}
```

When I launch the aplication I get a:

```
No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' available
```

What's wrong? I suppose I'm mixing annotation and xml configuration at least for the spring security but I need web.xml file because of previous configuration. Is there a way to solve this or I must use the *security-config.xml* instead of the configuration class I posted?

Thank you

Comment: Here are some solutions
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23573471/4727991

Comment: Those solution are completely different from my configuration, I don't have a WebInitializer and I don't have the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter (I have defined it in spring-servlet.xml). Come on guys

Comment: @James Please include in your question information about another spring configuration file with `component-scan` tag and leave comment under my answer if it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your `beans.xml` configuration file. You did not declare `component-scan` attribute and Spring does not know that you have a java security configuration.

Just add `<context:component-scan base-package="my.package"/>` to `beans.xml` and the error should disappear.